# For some reason Arial renders strangely sometimes

Tags: firefox

In Firefox, sometimes the Arial font renders strangely sometimes, as can be seen here: 
[image]

What could be causing this?

Comment: You're not zoomed in or out a small percent, are you? Like 95% or 105%?

Comment: No, I'm not, I'm afraid.

Comment: Looks normal to me, what is so "strange" about it?

Comment: @Breakthrough: Look at the video titles! That's not Arial. According to Firebug, it's supposed to be a plain old bold 16px Arial font.

Comment: @damd I get the exact same thing as you under Firefox, and that *is* plan old bold 16px Arial font.  It might be rendered partially different in a document viewer/editor, but I assure you there's nothing wrong with that screenshot.

Comment: @Breakthrough: You're right. Apparently the latest version of Firefox understands that 800 is not the same font-weight as "bold". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, what you see *is* normal viewing behavior for Firefox on the given website you posted.  As per the information you had posted, the "issue" was caused by Firefox's interpretation of font-weight (just for you reference, [700 is the font-weight](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) equivalent to bolding text).