# Arial font sometimes not rendering correctly in Google Docs (same account, same browser, same font, two documents)

Tags: firefox, fonts, google-docs

I've created two **Google Docs** document in Google Workspace (Google Drive) and pasted the same text. I selected all the text and removed all of the formatting. According to Google Docs, both are **Arial** font **11 pt**. but there's obviously a difference, one is really problematic in terms how the font is rendered with respect to spacing, etc.

The following screenshots are from the **same** Google Workspace (Google Drive) account, running **Firefox 92.0 (64-bit)**, on an up-to-date **Microsoft Windows 10**.

The problematic Google Docs example:

[image]

But when I create another empty Google Docs document and did the same thing (paste and remove formatting), somehow I get the following:

[image]

I can reproduce this issue when I create a new Google Docs document in a folder I've created a few weeks ago. Whenever I create a new document there, I get this Arial font not rendering properly. When I try creating a new Google Docs document in a totally different folder, I **don't** have that Arial font problem.

Any ideas?

I've checked the following but they don't seem to correspond to my situation exactly:

- [For some reason Arial renders strangely sometimes](https://superuser.com/questions/378940/for-some-reason-arial-renders-strangely-sometimes)
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1366880
- https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/9aci1j/arial_font_in_google_sheets_has_spacing_issues/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/k7quy3/font_issues_with_firefox_on_windows_10/

Comment: I get the same issue with Firefox 96 on Windows 10, whether the doc is created on my Android 11 phone, or from my browser. It's fine in Chrome and in the app on my phone. I hate having to make a copy of the doc to 'fix' it though - hopefully there will be some better fix for it.

Comment: Reported elsewhere on the internet: [Text font rendering issues in Google Docs when using Firefox. Looks fine on Chrome.](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/r0v7yl/text_font_rendering_issues_in_google_docs_when/) or [In Firefox 93.0, all fonts in Google Docs (and ONLY Docs) appear grainy/blurry.](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/129622603/in-firefox-93-0-all-fonts-in-google-docs-and-only-docs-appear-grainy-blurry?hl=en) or [GDocs has very poor glyph rendering with D2D canvas](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1730772)

Comment: If you have the ResistFingerprinting preference enabled in Firefox, that may be the culprit. Try fixing it with this userscript: https://github.com/hboyd2003/Privacyresistfingerprinting-Docs-Sheets-Fix (you will have to install a userscript manager like [FireMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemonkey/) first)

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue. It is pretty annoying. It can be solved by making a copy of the document you are working on and then deleting the former document and using the new document. I haven't found a better solution yet.